# MVC model out of range error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on my first MVC application and have run into an error.

I am trying to query a database and show the results on a view page.

here is the code

```
 public class foreclosureList
{
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfListings { get; set; }
}
public class RETS_ListingsModel
{

    public RETS_ListingsModel(){} // empty COnstructor

    public static IEnumerable<foreclosureList> getForeclosureList() // making an IEnumerable list to contain the forclosure data
    {
        SqlConnection myConn;
        SqlCommand myCmd;
        SqlDataReader myReader;

            System.Collections.ArrayList aforclosureList = new System.Collections.ArrayList(); // create an array to hold data, later it will be converted to the ienumerable list. 
            string mySql =
             "Select [Area], count (*) as numberListings from listingTable" +
             " Where ForeclosureYN = 'Y'" +
             " AND Area <> ''" +
             " Group By Area";

            myConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);
            myCmd = myConn.CreateCommand();
            myCmd.CommandText = mySql;
            myConn.Open();

            foreclosureList currentList = new foreclosureList(); // making an instance foreclosureList class and then adding the results from the query.

            myReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {

                currentList.Area = (string)myReader["Area"];
                currentList.NumberOfListings = (int)myReader["NumberOfListings"];
                aforclosureList.Add(currentList); // adding the class object to the array
            }


            myReader.Close();
            myConn.Close();

            IEnumerable<foreclosureList> iforeclosureList = aforclosureList.Cast<foreclosureList>(); //converting the array back to the ienumerable list
            return iforeclosureList;
        }

    }
```

But I am getting an error saying:
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: NumberOfListings

Also on my view page, in order to access this data am I correct in using the following code on line 1

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Foreclosure.Models.foreclosureList>" %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
string mySql =
"Select [Area], count (*) as numberListings from listingTable" 

...
currentList.NumberOfListings = (int)myReader["NumberOfListings"];
```

You don't fetch anything called `NumberOfListings`. You fetch `numberListings`. They're not the same.

Additionally, you should use `using` statements for your connection, statement and reader, change your code to follow .NET naming conventions, stop using `ArrayList` (favouring `List<T>` instead) and potentially move to something like LINQ instead of manual SQL (which would have avoided this error).

Comment: UGH! Thank you VERY much - I hate when I make such stupid errors!